# Two Date Criteria in DMin Function in VBA Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table with Multiple Date Fields like

```
DOB (Date), 
DOA_ASST(Date), 
DOA_UDC (Date)
```

and also have some fields like

```
ID (AutoNumber), 
EmpID (Integer), 
EmpName (Text), 
SeniorityNumber (Integer) etc.
```

Many of Employee Promoted Same Date and Also Have the same date of Appointment. I want to provide serial no as per their seniority according to their first date of Appointment.

Criteria are following-

1. if Multiple Employee Promoted on the Same date then Date of Appointment with older date will be considered, if Date of Appointment are same then Date of Birth with Older date will be considered.

I tried the following code:-

```
Private Sub cmdProcess_Click()
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim rst1 As Recordset

Dim LastSN As Integer
Dim str, strAsst, strUDC, strLDC As String
Dim LDCDate, UDCDate, AsstDate, BirthDate As Date

AsstDate = Nz(DMax("[DOP_ASST]", "tblDraftSeniority"), DMin("[DOP_ASST]", "tblRawSeniority"))
UDCDate = DMin("[DOP_UDC]", "tblRawSeniority", "[DOP_ASST] = #" & AsstDate & "#")
LDCDate = DMin("[DOA_ESIC]", "tblRawSeniority", "[DOP_UDC] =  #" & UDCDate & "# AND [DOP_ASST] = #" & AsstDate & "#")
BirthDate = DMin("[DOB]", "tblRawSeniority", "[DOA_ESIC] =  #" & LDCDate & "#")

LastSN = DLookup("[ID]", "tblRawSeniority", "[DOB] =  #" & BirthDate & "#")

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblRawSeniority")
Set rst1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblDraftSeniority")

rst.MoveLast
rst.MoveFirst
Do While rst.EOF = False

    If rst!ID = LastSN Then

        With rst
            Me.txtEmpName1 = rst!EmpName
            Me.txtEmpCatg1 = rst!Category
            Me.txtEmpDOB1 = rst!DOB
            Me.txtEmpDOEntry1 = rst!DOA_ESIC
            Me.txtEmpDONextPromo1 = rst!DOP_UDC
            Me.txtEmpDOCurrentPromo1 = rst!DOP_ASST
            Me.txtEmpStateRegion1 = rst!Region
            Me.txtRemark1 = rst!Remark
            Me.txtSN1 = rst!SrNoHQRS

        End With
    End If

    rst.MoveNext

Loop

Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```

But there is `null` value in `LDCDate` with Two date Criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since rst1 is not used, and you are only looking up one ID, you could try something like:

```vb
Private Sub cmdProcess_Click()

    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    Dim LastSN As Long
    Dim LDCDate As Date
    Dim UDCDate As Date
    Dim AsstDate As Date
    Dim BirthDate As Date

    AsstDate = Nz(DMax("[DOP_ASST]", "tblDraftSeniority"), DMin("[DOP_ASST]", "tblRawSeniority"))
    UDCDate = Nz(DMin("[DOP_UDC]", "tblRawSeniority", "[DOP_ASST] = #" & Format(AsstDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"), DMax("[DOP_UDC]", "tblRawSeniority"))
    LDCDate = Nz(DMin("[DOA_ESIC]", "tblRawSeniority", "[DOP_UDC] =  #" & Format(UDCDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# AND [DOP_ASST] = #" & Format(AsstDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"), DMax("[DOP_ESIC]", "tblRawSeniority"))
    BirthDate = DMin("[DOB]", "tblRawSeniority", "[DOA_ESIC] =  #" & Format(LDCDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#")

    LastSN = Nz(DLookup("[ID]", "tblRawSeniority", "[DOB] =  #" & Format(BirthDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"), Date)

    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblRawSeniority")

    rst.FindFirst "ID = " & LastSN & ""
    If Not rst.NoMatch Then    
        Me.txtEmpName1 = rst!EmpName
        Me.txtEmpCatg1 = rst!Category
        Me.txtEmpDOB1 = rst!DOB
        Me.txtEmpDOEntry1 = rst!DOA_ESIC
        Me.txtEmpDONextPromo1 = rst!DOP_UDC
        Me.txtEmpDOCurrentPromo1 = rst!DOP_ASST
        Me.txtEmpStateRegion1 = rst!Region
        Me.txtRemark1 = rst!Remark
        Me.txtSN1 = rst!SrNoHQRS
    End If
    rst.Close

    Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are allowing null values for AsstDate, you are most likely using a null value (or 0) in the criteria for the LDCDate DMin lookup.  If your table doesn't actually have nulls in the DOP_ASST field, then your LDCDate will be null because there is no result found.

Comment: My above function retrieve actual value from table for both AsstDate and UDCDate but the problem with LDCDate (Null Value)